# kill mapper with error file in mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

Hello I need to kill the mapper which contains the error file.
When the file is parsed in mapper if the file contains error it should kill the current mapper and discard the file. Other mapper with correct files should continue and entire job should be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the File input format, the mapper may or may not be processing entire file a time. 
Generally each mapper will process a Split at time.

If there is any parsing issue you can simply skip processing records and return from mapper. No need to kill the mapper. If you kill that mapper, MapReduce job will fail.

So, just skip the processing and return from mapper.